# javafx charts not working

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

[image]

I am using javafx charts for my project and after running my program I am getting this chart. what I want it to snap 3rd point first and then on to 4th point. Is there any way to do that. Thanks

Comment: come on... you should put more effort in asking questions. If you would see this question, would you see any chance in answering this precicely ?

Comment: Sorry mate, this is my first question on StackOverflow. I have tried to clear my question now. Hopefully now I can get an answer

Comment: Use a different type of chart to display your data. PieChart maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the 'AreaChart' that you're using plots data monotonically.  So no matter what order the points get added to your series, the chart will plot them as monotonic.

note: Monotonic means that for every x value, there is a single y value.

If you want to break the 'monotonicness' of your plot and you're willing to give up the shaded area, you could construct it as a lineChart and then you would  need to change your sorting policy.  I've attached an example below to show you how to fix it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Pane root = new Pane();

    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    LineChart chart = new LineChart(xAxis,yAxis);

    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

    chart.getData().add(series);
    chart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.NONE);

    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0,1));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1,2));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2,1));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1,0));

    root.getChildren().add(chart);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if you're looking for both, it's going to come down to having to build your own chart class by extending from XYChart or maybe even AreaChart and defining your own custom AreaChart.

Comment: Also an additional note... 

The sorting is enumerated, therefore you can sort by the X axis, Y axis, or None